# Trying to iterate through CSV files in a directory and grab a particular cell then post results to a single csv

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to iterate through several CSV files in a directory and grab a particular cell (same cell location) from each CSV file (cell location found when opened in Excel) and then post all similar cells in a single CSV or xls file, one after the other.

I have writen the code below (with some researched help) but I am just iterating over the first csv file in my list and printing the same value each time, dependant on the number of CSV files in my list.  Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Here's my poor attempt!

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
import csv
import glob
import os


files = ['1_IQ_QTA.csv','2_IQ_QTA.csv','3_IQ_QTA.csv','4_IQ_QTA.csv']
n = 0
row = 0
filename = ('outputList.csv', 'a')
fname = files[n]
workbookr = xlrd.open_workbook(fname)
sheetr = workbookr.sheet_by_index(0)
workbookw = xlwt.Workbook()
sheetw = workbookw.add_sheet('test')

while n<len(files):
    fname = files[n]
    workbookr = xlrd.open_workbook(fname[n])
    data = [sheetr.cell_value(12, 1) for col in range(sheetr.ncols)]

    for index, value in enumerate(data):
        sheetw.write(row, index, value)
        workbookw.save('outputList.csv')
    row = row +1
    n = n+1    

workbookw.save('outputList.csv')
```

My code is still a bit messy, I may have leftover code from my various attempts!

Thanks
MikG

Comment: I'm a little surprised that `xlrd` can read `.csv` files.  I tried it myself and kept getting errors like `xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found '1.0,1.0,'`.  Are you sure they're `csv` files, or is my `xlrd` out of date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are just trying to make a CSV file of the same cells from each file.  So if you had 4 files, your output file will have 4 entries.

```
files = ['1_IQ_QTA.csv','2_IQ_QTA.csv','3_IQ_QTA.csv','4_IQ_QTA.csv']
n = 0
row = 0
outputfile = open('outputList.csv', 'w')
cellrow = 12 #collect the cell (12, 1) from each file and put it in the output list
cellcolumn = 1
while n<len(files):
    fname = files[n]
    currentfile = open(fname,'r')
    for i in range (cellrow):
        currentrow = currentfile.readline()
#        print currentrow #for testing
    columncnt=0
    currentcell = ''
    openquote = False
    for char in currentrow:
        if char == '"' and not openquote:
            openquote = True
        elif char == '"' and openquote:
            openquote = False
        elif char == ',' and not openquote:
            columncnt+=1
            if columncnt == cellcolumn:
                cellvalue = currentcell
#                print cellvalue #for testing
            currentcell=''
        else:
            currentcell += char

    outputfile.write (cellvalue + ',')
    currentfile.close()
    n += 1

outputfile.close()
```

It seemed to me that since you already had a CSV it would be easier to deal with as a regular file and parse through to find the right information, plus nothing to import.  Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quickly.  Yes, the plan is to get four entries (one cell copied from each file) into a new csv.

Comment: Hi town_math.  Thanks for your help, just one quick question, I tried your example, but near the end on line >> outputfile.write (cellvalue + ',')  <<  it is throwing up an error of cellvalue not defined, where would I need redefine cellvalue in the above code?

Comment: It looks like I forgot to initialize it, that might be the problem.  You could add cellvalue='' instead of row=0 which I forgot to erase anyway.  Though if you are getting their error, I am guessing your columncnt never gets up to your cellcolumn value.  Try uncommenting the print cellvalue to see if it actually does that.

Comment: Thanks town_math, it looks like it is now doing something, however my out put is a group of strangte characters like this.. ◄αí▒ .  The cell in question would be a number of 0.345 or similar.

Comment: If it it isn't sensitive information, could you post the .csv files so I could try it out?

Comment: The data is potentially sensitive so I cannot post it. I can say that when I do run the script in the output file I get a series of ,,,, in one cell (A:1) corresponding to the number of files.  Perhaps I will have to convert to xls :( and resubmit the question.

Comment: Ok no worries, it works fine on my test files, so I don't know where the problem is on your end.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error at this line in the while loop:

```
workbookr = xlrd.open_workbook(fname[n])
```

must be:

```
workbookr = xlrd.open_workbook(fname)
```

otherwise your workbookr remains as you set it before outside the loop:

```
fname = files[n]
workbookr = xlrd.open_workbook(fname)
```

which is the first file in your list.

Comment: Thanks, I mistakenly left that (fname[n]) entry in my code when I was playing about trying to find a solution.  I have removed it from my code, but I still get a repeated list of 4 entries in my generated csv with the cell obtained from the first csv file only.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are just csv files, there is no need for the excel libraries.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse, csv
if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='merge csv files on field', version='%(prog)s 1.0')
    parser.add_argument('infile', nargs='+', type=str, help='list of input files')
    parser.add_argument('--col', type=int, default=0, help='Column to grab')
    parser.add_argument('--row', type=int, default=0, help='Row to grab')
    parser.add_argument('--out', type=str, default='temp.csv', help='name of output file')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    data = []

    for fname in args.infile:
        with open(fname, 'rb') as df:
            reader = csv.reader(df)
            for index, line in enumerate(reader):
                if index == args.row:
                    data.push(line[args.column])
            del reader

    writer = csv.writer(open(args.out, "wb"), dialect='excel')
    writer.writerows(data)
    del writer
```

Comment: Hi Spencer,Thanks for your reply, I tried your example, but I would be intereseted to know how to represent my input files in your 'infile' argument.  Should I define a list before the code or can I add them as '1file.csv','2file.csv','3file.csv'

Comment: @MikG since this is all in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` section, it will only run when invoked from the command line. Running `python thescript.py file1.csv file2.csv ./dir/*.csv` will work just fine. I've updated it so that the row and col args are flags with defaults.